# Find scope outside of a within block

Tags: capybara

From within a within block I would like to access the page scope.  Details being that the code in the within block activates some javascript that generates some html outside that scope.

```
within("some_scope") do
  find("something").click # that opens some html outside some_scope
  without("outer_thing").click
  <more finding and doing of things within scope>
end
```

Is there a way to do `without`?  Yes, this is a trivial example and the actual code is a bit more complicated and yes I could use multiple within blocks - but I don't wanna.  Is there a good clean way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no public API to go back up one layer of 'within' scope, but you can get access back to the top level by using 'page.document' inside the within block